# Calling a method to print an array[][] using array as a parameter

Tags: arrays, methods, parameters

Here the overall goal is to create a method that will use parameters including an array and an integer based on what the user chooses. I want it to print a 5x5 array in order and then if the user decided in reverse.

I am having trouble calling the method to test if the first part is working.

**Here is what I have:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class arrayPrinter

//printer method meant to print the 2d array normally 

public static void printarray (int iarray[][], int entry )
  {

if ( entry == 0 )

{

 for ( int iarrprint [] : iarray )
 {

  System.out.println ( Arrays.toString (iarrprint));
 }
}

else
{
}

return;
  }

  //main method

  public static void main (String args[])
  {
//5 by 5 array created

    int iarray [][] = new int [5][5];


    // array populated with random numbers between 1 and 100
    for (int irow = 0; irow < iarray.length; irow++)
    {
      for (int icol = 0; icol < iarray[irow].length; icol++)
      {
      Random rnum = new Random();
      int igen = Math.abs(rnum.nextInt (100));
      iarray [irow][icol] = igen;
      }
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ( "Print array in order? Press 0 / Print the array in reverse? Press 1" );
    int testvalue = sc.nextInt();
    printarray ( iarray[][], testvalue ); //error .class expected


  }
```

I am hoping to become more comfortable using arrays but I get caught up on little stuff.

I get the error **.class expected**.

Any suggestions would be GREAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invoke the method as follows:

```
printarray ( iarray, testvalue ); // you don't need [][] here
```

Comment: I feel so silly for it being such a little thing. That fixed it. Thank you so much!